# Suspicious of losing Wudu during prayer

Tags: halal-haram, salat, wudu, doubts

Salam ‘aleykoum,
If I think I may have lost my Wudu but I keep praying in case I didn’t loose it, is it haram?

Answer (score 1):

Salam 'Alaykum,
You can continue your Salah/prayer without interrupting it, as long as you do not hear a sound or smell something. Because of the hadith:

> Narrated `Abbas bin Tamim:
> that his uncle said: "The Prophet (ﷺ) was asked: If a person feels something during his prayer; should one interrupt his prayer?" The Prophet (ﷺ) said: No! You should not give it up unless you hear a sound or smell something." Narrated Ibn Abi Hafsa: Az-Zuhri said, "There is no need of repeating ablution unless you detect a smell or hear a sound." [Sahih Al-Bukhari 2056](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2056)

So, you need not interrupt your prayer if you don't detect a smell or hear a sound.

And Allah knows best.